# An if-else block in Redis source (Simple Dynamic Strings) which i couldn't understand

Tags: c, redis

Firstly, i'm really sorry for the title but i have no other idea about how can i tell in otherwise.

I'm trying to understand [Simple Dynamic Strings](http://redis.io/topics/internals-sds) and between lines 138-141 in [sds.c](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2.8/src/sds.c#L138) there is an if-else block which i couldn't understand. I don't even know why is it there and i don't know what it does too.

The relevant function is:

```
/* Enlarge the free space at the end of the sds string so that the caller
* is sure that after calling this function can overwrite up to addlen
* bytes after the end of the string, plus one more byte for nul term.
*
* Note: this does not change the *length* of the sds string as returned
* by sdslen(), but only the free buffer space we have. */
sds sdsMakeRoomFor(sds s, size_t addlen) {
    struct sdshdr *sh, *newsh;
    size_t free = sdsavail(s);
    size_t len, newlen;

    if (free >= addlen) return s;
    len = sdslen(s);
    sh = (void*) (s-(sizeof(struct sdshdr)));
    newlen = (len+addlen);
    if (newlen < SDS_MAX_PREALLOC) /* unwind: line 138 */
        newlen *= 2;
    else
        newlen += SDS_MAX_PREALLOC;
    newsh = zrealloc(sh, sizeof(struct sdshdr)+newlen+1);
    if (newsh == NULL) return NULL;

    newsh->free = newlen - len;
    return newsh->buf;
}
```

Sorry for such a noob question but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you understand *what* it does, but not *why*.

The what is that is doubles the increment of the size of the buffer being allocated to hold the string, if the computed increment is considered "too small".

The why is to increase performance: if the string continues to grow (as dynamic strings are able to do), Redis won't need to reallocate a new buffer quite as soon as it would otherwise have had to. This is good, since `realloc()` is costly.

Basically, it's buying performance by spending memory, a very common trade-off.